# Mathematically Corrupt Rebus

Tags: rebus

What does the following rebus represent?

```
|
|
|

⌊edifices.⌋ ++ |clone| + |collapsed| ++ ⌈Shrub⌉+ |the|
```

Hint:

> it's probably a three-word affirmation

Second Hint:

> If you got the sentence right, there's steel a "picture" in it ;)

Comment: Is this about the rot13( gjva gbjref )

Comment: The use of floor and ceiling brackets definitely interests me.

Comment: It appears to be a hint that Shrub is the first word. It's capitalized and has the ceiling brackets. The rest are pipes. Then edifices has a period and a floor tag. Almost as if the words are stacked on top of each other and boxed in. But collapsed clone edifices makes me think... @Deusovi

Comment: @Z.Dailey: Your thoughts were correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence is

> Shrub collapsed the clone edifices.

Substituting words for their synonyms, we get the phrase

> "Bush collapsed the twin towers"

representing the common meme

> "Bush did 9/11".

The picture is:

> `|
>          |
>          |
>     ⌈  Shrub  ⌉
>     |collapsed|   +
>     |   the   |  ++++
>     |  clone  |   +
>     ⌊edifices.⌋`

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure and kinda felt that the puzzle might be in poor taste. Didn't want to post it and be wrong and offensive at the same time. >.>

Comment: @Z.Dailey: Agreed, it absolutely *is* in poor taste. But it's an internet meme, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yah. I wasn't thinking of the meme as much as a political statement. ;)

Comment: And lest we forget `Jet fuel can't melt steel beams`

Answer (score 1):

Totally wild shot, is it

> A Tree Grows in Brooklyn

Maybe 'cause

> The first three "cloned edifices collapsed" mean "the twin towers...".
>  But just to get to New York City in a twisted crass way.
>  And Brooklyn is the most populous of New York City's five boroughs.
>  The capitalized "Shrub" means "tree" and the ceiling function means it's "growing".
>  The bars around "the" are squeezing it down to an "a".
>  The 3 lines on the left-hand side are an extremely poor ascii-art of a tree!

Comment: Wow, you're really creative... and I'm not